# PHP - How to rename the uploaded file?

Tags: php, upload, rename

I am trying to upload the file with a different name as to the one it came with on upload? I have looked at the php rename function but I can't work out how to get the original file name. I got this code here [LINK TO CODE](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";











    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Just change the filename in the target portion of the move_uploaded_file call

Comment: `move_uploaded_file($_FILEblahbalbha, $name_you_want)`. There's nothing magical about it. m_u_f doesn't make up its own filenames. it uses names YOU provide.

Comment: `if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {`  Okay I have really just started php where do I put the file name I want in? @MarcB

Comment: RTFM? http://php.net/move_uploaded_file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first we're creating the new file name and appending it to `$newFileName` variable and then we're going to move the uploaded file to the new file name variable that we just created

```
     <?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$newFileName = $target_dir .'YourfileName'.'.'. pathinfo($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"] ,PATHINFO_EXTENSION); //get the file extension and append it to the new file name
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"] ,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"],  $newFileName)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";

    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I have tried your code but I will not upload the file and come up with the message "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file." please could you check the code?? thanks @Diyar Baban

Comment: oops my bad sorry will fix it for you one second

Comment: i updated my answer, and sorry i was on rush

Comment: Thanks that works perfect :)